# Object creation syntax difference

Tags: scala

Is there a difference between `new ClassName` and `new ClassName()`? Is it only a syntax difference or is there a scala magic happening in the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only a syntax difference, as far as I know. Example using the scala REPL:

```
scala> val foo = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
foo: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Nothing,Nothing] = Map()

scala> val foo = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap()
foo: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Nothing,Nothing] = Map()
```

I think this is simply an example of the normal behavior in Scala where it is allowed to omit the parenthesis when calling a method without arguments.